# Footnotes with and without numbers

Tags: footnotes

I needed two levels of footnotes without numbers, so I put at the beginning of the document what follows:

```
\DeclareNewFootnote{default} 
\DeclareNewFootnote{B} [arabic]
\let\extrafootnoterule\footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=100
\makeatletter 
    \def\@makefnmark{} 
\makeatother 
\newcommand{\myfootnote}[2]{\footnote{\textbf{#1}: #2}}
\makeatother
```

But now there is a section of the thesis in which I would like to have the numbers again. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). // Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you”.

Comment: Ok, I will do it next time!

Comment: Also, a full MWE would help.  By searching around I discovered that this requires the bigfoot package, which in turn requires manyfoot (also known as ncctools).

Comment: Aha!  \DeclareNewFootnote{B} defines macro \thefootnoteB.